# OpenCV: mathematical operations on matrices like in Matlab

Tags: opencv

I have a pretty basic question.

The below Matlab code takes 2 matrices with same dimensions `(matrix1, matrix2)`, and produces a new matrix, `result_matrix`, which in each index `(i,j)`, it contains `sqrt(matrix1[i][j] ^ 2  + matrix2[i][j] ^ 2)`.

How would you convert this simple Matlab code into OpenCV in C++, such that it would be most simple, clear and efficient?

```
result_matrix = sqrt(matrix1 .^ 2 + matrix2 .^ 2);
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with OpenCV, so don't take this comment too seriously, but if you've looked at their documentation and found out you have to do the matrix math in your C++ code, then you need to create a data structure to hold your matrices (e.g. recommend a class, though bi-dimensional arrays can also work) and write the logic for adding two matrices together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the matrices a, b, c

```
Mat a;
Mat b;
Mat c;
```

you can do this:

```
pow(a, 2, a);
pow(b, 2, b);
sqrt(a + b, c);
```

At the end `c` will contain the result. See docs for [`pow()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20pow(InputArray%20src,%20double%20power,%20OutputArray%20dst)) and [`sqrt()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20sqrt(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst)) the sum is done via the + operator on Mat, see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions)

Comment: So simple!! Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

For this specific operation:

```
result_matrix = sqrt(matrix1 .^ 2 + matrix2 .^ 2);
```

you can use [magnitude](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude):

```
Mat m1 = ...
Mat m2 = ...
Mat m3;
magnitude(m1, m2, m3);
```

This is 3-4 times faster than @mirosval code.

Comment: Works great, thank you! I will leave @mirosval 's answer as the accepted one, because this question was more general about mathematical operations.